# Retrieve all carts

Tags: cart, soap, quote

Why can't I retrieve all carts belongs to the store using a 'cart.list' call? And is there any substitution if I needed to retrieve all carts? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box. However, creating your own API isn't that hard. [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785) should help you along

The business end that collects the quotes would be

`app/code/local/Envato/Customapimodule/Model/Product/Api.php`

```
class Envato_Customapimodule_Model_Product_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
  public function items()
  {
    $_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect(array('entity_id', 'subtotal', 'etc'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $store)
        ->addFieldToFilter([...]) // any filters you might want

    $quotes = array();
    foreach ($_collection as $_item) {
      $quotes[] = (array)$_item->getData();
    }

    return $quotes;
  }
}
```